# How do I fetch input from select box using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap, web, thymeleaf

I have been doing school's project recently and started learning Java Web/Spring/Bootstrap and stuff only a week ago, so please do forgive and correct me if I got any idea wrong.

So I was working on some webpage following an online tutorial and it's really great that I can fetch user's input by using Thymeleaf tags like codes below

```html
<div class="ip input-group" align="center">
    <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" th:value="*{username}"/>
</div>
```

Though I'm having a hard time trying to fetch input from select box or radio button like codes below (am I doing anything wrong here?)

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <select class="btn btn-default" th:value="*{sex}">
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>Fmale</option>
        <option>Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Since it's able to fetch input from simple input area, I'm thinking that there should be a way to acquire input or data from select box or radio button by using Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `th:field` tag should be in `<select>` tag, but it does not exist.
2. `th:value` tag should be in `<option>` tag, not in `<select>` tag.

As described in thymeleaf docs:

> Select fields have two parts: the  tag and its nested 
>   tags. When creating this kind of field, only the  tag has to
>   include a th:field attribute, but the th:value attributes in the
>   nested  tags will be very important because they will provide
>   the means of knowing which is the currently selected option (in a
>   similar way to non-boolean checkboxes and radio buttons).

[Code snipped](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#dropdownlist-selectors) in source